# How to get multiple columns data into the same cell with a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need get an sql result that gets multiple columns data from a table into a single cell for the result. How would be the query?

Let's suppose I have this 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
Name     spec
--------------
James    front
--------------
Henry    front
--------------
Henry    back
```

Table 2:

```
Name     dir
--------------
James    123
--------------
Henry    456
```

And I want to get this result:

Result Table:

```
Name     spec     dir
-----------------------
James    front    123
-----------------------
Henry    front    456
         back
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `group_concat()` function

```
    select a.name, group_concat(spec SEPARATOR ' '),dir
    from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.name=b.name
    group by a.name,dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for that problem is calling a join. A join combines multiple tables into one using certain identifiers. In your problem the identifier is the name. An example solution would be:

```
select table1.name, table2.spec, table2.dir
    from table1 inner join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example:](https://rextester.com/SKCUWM68920) **GROUP_CONCAT** is correct, but if you want spec column value print in new line then use '**\n**'

```
SELECT a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(spec SEPARATOR '\n'),dir
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.name=b.name)
GROUP BY a.name,dir;
```